# Split as delete/insert/insert in QGIS

Tags: qgis, splitting

Default behavior of split in GIS software is mostly to update feature (row) for first part of split geometry, and insert copies for all other parts.

For many reasons this might not be desired behavior though, and instead delete original row, and insert all parts as new might be preferred.

In ArcGIS Pro - *Catalogue - Feature Class Properties - Source* tab there is option **Split Model** which can be switched from **Update/Insert** to **Delete/Insert/Insert**.

How to do this in QGIS?

Comment: **Processing - Split Vector Layer** (with output to shapefile) creates a new shapefile for each class of feature (based on value of a field). Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: About the many reasons, I can imagine only one reason and that is to assign new fids for all the parts. What other reasons do you have?

Comment: OpenJUMP seems to delete the original and insert two new polygons by default. There is no option to update the original but it is possible to keep the original and add the two halves.

Comment: @user30184 Thank you. I have triggers on tables in database which do different things on insert, and update, e.g. editor tracking assigns user to edited by or created by, there are other things too. It is not like I can't sort it out on database level. Just would make things a bit easier and consistent.

Comment: Perhaps modify your question to indicate that you are talking about an **SQL database**.

Comment: @wingnut Thank you. I am asking about split features function which can be applied to any editable line or polygon vector layer in QGIS.

Comment: Maybe that option would not give much advantage when layer comes from formats like GeoJSON or even shapefile where the FID is like a rownum counter. Probably you could copy the geometry, split the copy, and delete the original but that feels like a poor workaround.